# trouble detatching terminal sessions with PHP shell_exec()

Tags: php, shell-exec, nohup

I maintain a game server and unruly players frequently crash the application. My moderation team needs the ability to restart the server process, but allowing ssh access would be impractical/insecure, so im using shell exec to pass the needed commands to restart the server process from a web based interface. The problem is, the shell session doesnt detatch properly and thus php maintains its session untill it finally times out and closes the session/stops the server process.
Here's how I'm calling shell_exec:
$command='nohup java -jar foobar_server.jar';
shell_exec($command);

Answer (score 0):

shell_exec will wait until the command you've executed returns (e.g. drops back to a shell prompt). If you want to run that as a background task, so shelL_exec returns immediately, then do

```
$command='nohup java -jar foobar_server.jar &'; 
                                            ^--- run in background
```

Of course, that assumes you're doing this on a unix/linux host. For windows, it'd be somewhat different.

Comment: this didin't work...hangs the same way nohup does without &. Thanks though!

Comment: Because theres no output redirection PHP keeps a hold on the i/o pipes of the process you're shell_exec()ing. To add to the previous suggestion, also append some i/o redirection to the command line like so: $command = 'nohup java -jar foobar_server.jar 2>&1 >/dev/null &';

Comment: Doing so will redirect the error stream into the normal stdout stream (2>&1) then redirect all stdout (including now stderr) to /dev/null. This allows PHP to completely let go of the child process.

Answer (score 0):

If you try this you'd see it won't work. To fully detach in PHP you must also do stdout redirection else shell_exec will hang even with '&'.

This is what you'd really want:

```
shell_exec('java -jar foobar_server.jar >/dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

But to take this one step further, I would get rid of the web interface and make this a one-minute interval cronjob which first checks if the process is running, and if it's not start a new instance:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! pidof foobar_server.jar; then
    java -jar foobar_server.jar >/tmp/foobar_server.log 2>&1 &;
fi
```

And have that run every minute, if it finds a running process it does nothing, else it starts a new instance. Worst case scenerio after a server crash is 59 seconds downtime.

Cheers

Comment: This seems like it may work, so I'm going to try this...
However, a minute by minute CRON job wouldn't work. Sometimes the server will become unresponsive but not actually "crash", and thus it's process stays in memory, but in a completely useless state...
Still, I'll try your method and see what happens!